# False jailbroken detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

the following code detects Jailbroken devices:

```
BOOL isJailbroken() {
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Applications/Cydia.app"] ||
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib"] ||
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/bin/bash"] ||
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/usr/sbin/sshd"] ||
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/etc/apt"] ||
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/var/lib/apt/"] ||
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"cydia://package/com.example.package"]])  {
        return YES;
    }

    FILE *f = NULL ;
    if ((f = fopen("/bin/bash", "r")) ||
        (f = fopen("/Applications/Cydia.app", "r")) ||
        (f = fopen("/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib", "r")) ||
        (f = fopen("/usr/sbin/sshd", "r")) ||
        (f = fopen("/etc/apt", "r")))  {
        fclose(f);
        return YES;
    }
    fclose(f);

    NSError *error;
    NSString *stringToBeWritten = @"afa s";
    [stringToBeWritten writeToFile:@"/private/jailbreak.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:@"/private/jailbreak.txt" error:nil];
    if(error == nil)
    {
        return YES;
    }

#endif

    return NO;
}
```

We have many clients who claim that their devices are **brand new** but the above mentioned code returns YES on their devices because /private/var/lib/apt path exists.

Is this normal? Are they lying? Are the sellers lying or Apple does something odd on some of their devices before they ship them?

Comment: I don't know the technical answer but if it's "many clients", then either they're  **not** lying or you have an unusual client demographic.

Comment: Sidenote: `/private/var/lib/apt/` persists across restores if the device is upgraded rather than erased, so you might wanna omit that.